# javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: java.security.DigestException: Length must be at least 32 for SHA-256digests

Tags: java, encryption, bouncycastle, smartcard, pkcs#11

I am getting below exception after decrypting using `"RSA/ECB/NoPadding"` algorithm and removing OAEP padding using [the approach given by divanov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23853610/589259).

```
Caused by: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: java.security.DigestException: Length must be at least 32 for SHA-256digests
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.mgf1(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadOAEP(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpad(Unknown Source)
```

Used the same code but it didn't work for me.

The only change I made in the code is following :

```
Provider pkcs11provider = new SunPKCS11("C:\\Users\\manishs525\\pkcs11.cfg");
Cipher rsaCipher2 = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/NoPadding", pkcs11provider);
rsaCipher2.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
byte[] paddedPlainText = rsaCipher2.doFinal(cipherText);

/* Ensure leading zeros not stripped */
if (paddedPlainText.length < keyLength / 8) {
    byte[] tmp = new byte[keyLength / 8];
    System.arraycopy(paddedPlainText, 0, tmp, tmp.length - paddedPlainText.length, paddedPlainText.length);
    System.out.println("Zero padding to " + (keyLength / 8));
    paddedPlainText = tmp;
}           

System.out.println("OAEP padded plain text: " + DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(paddedPlainText));
// === changed the next line ===
PSource pSrc = (new PSource.PSpecified(iv));
// === changed the last two parameters to MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA256 and pSrc ===
OAEPParameterSpec paramSpec = new OAEPParameterSpec("SHA-256", "MGF1", MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA256, pSrc);   // where iv is byte array of length 32
RSAPadding padding = RSAPadding.getInstance(RSAPadding.PAD_OAEP_MGF1, keyLength / 8, new SecureRandom(), paramSpec);
byte[] plainText2 = padding.unpad(paddedPlainText);
```

Comment: Please show us where this hint of divanov is given. **Never** use Sun internal classes; use Bouncy Castle lightlweight API as you have to. Oracle may change location and/or implementation at any time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23844694/bad-padding-exception-rsa-ecb-oaepwithsha-256andmgf1padding-in-pkcs11/23853610#23853610

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no reason to specify any `PSource`. In the standards, it seems always empty, allowing for "future extension".

Are you sure that not just the outside hash is SHA-256? There is no particular security reason to replace the default MGF...

Comment: iv comes as parameter in function which is of length 32

Comment: Yes, but why? Are you trying to decrypt according to some kind of special protocol? If so, don't you think we should read and understand the protocol before we can help you?