# RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding but with MGF1 using SHA-256?

Tags: java, cryptography

I found the hard way that in Oracle's Java standard crypto provider

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding");
```

uses MFG1 instanciated with SHA-1; SHA-256 is only used to hash the label (in practice empty). The only solution that I found to actually use SHA-256 in MFG1 (helped by that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23853610/903600) and [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23844694/903600#comment51171514_23853610)) was using an alternate form of `Cipher.init`:

```
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privKey, new OAEPParameterSpec(
    "SHA-256", "MGF1", MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA256, PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT
));
```

Question: is there a *transformation* that `Cipher.getInstance` will recognize, with effect similar to `"RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding"`, except with MGF1 using SHA-256?

Comment: Note that this works only since Java7u55 (see https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8058549). Previous java versions throw an Exception doing it the described way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, there isn't.

Java is open source. If unsure you can take a look at the sources for the OpenJDK.

In the `init` method of [`com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/sun/crypto/provider/RSACipher.java.html) it reads:

```
            spec = new OAEPParameterSpec(oaepHashAlgorithm, "MGF1",
                MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA1, PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT);
```

I've checked this up to Java 8 update 60 for the OpenJDK. As you can see, you need to use the algorithm parameters.

Comment: Convincing demonstration, thanks. This is a serious oversight IMHO. One of the justification of the complexity of the Java standard crypto provider is to allow specifying a _transformation_ in a unified way, as implicit in the [specification of Cipher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html): "A _transformation_ is a string that describes the operation (or set of operations) to be performed on the given input, to produce some output."

Comment: I agree with that, it also hampers the replacement of e.g. RSA/PKCS1 or OAEP with one that uses SHA-256. There have been more of such oversights, such as AES not having a `SecretKeyFactory`, which would be required for use with e.g. HSM's. GCM has not been handled gracefully either. Still one of the best API's around none-the-less.

Comment: Old post, but just for the record, it looks like Java 8 parses the MD from the transformation string now: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/com/sun/crypto/provider/RSACipher.java/#147

Comment: @eckes: I do not see the code around the line that you mention choosing the hash for MGF1. Plus, if it does, there must be a specification somewhere, right?

Comment: @fgrieu I thought it is `oaepHashAlgorithm`, but maybe I am wrong (it might be the label hash). BTW: I suspect it is not specified as it is not a JCE standard but implemented for JSSE, but I could be wrong.