# lHash mismatch error in decryption of encrypeted SecretKeyData

Tags: java, encryption

When i decrypt encrypted SecretKeyData with private key which is stored in HSM receive

> javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: lHash mismatch
>           at in.gov.uidai.kyc.client.RSAPadding.unpadOAEP(RSAPadding.java:396)
>           at in.gov.uidai.kyc.client.RSAPadding.unpad(RSAPadding.java:244)
>           at in.gov.uidai.kyc.client.RSAPadding.unpad(RSAPadding.java:227)
>           at in.gov.uidai.kyc.client.DataDecryptorNew.decryptSecretKeyData(DataDec
>   ryptorNew.java:437)

```
 private byte[] decryptSecretKeyData(byte[] encryptedSecretKey, byte[] iv) throws Exception {

    try {
        Cipher rsaCipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION_NOPADDING, providerPKCS11);
        rsaCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
        byte[] paddedPlainText = rsaCipher.doFinal(encryptedSecretKey);

        /* Ensure leading zeros not stripped */
        if (paddedPlainText.length < keyLength / 8) {
            byte[] tmp = new byte[keyLength / 8];
            System.arraycopy(paddedPlainText, 0, tmp, tmp.length - paddedPlainText.length, paddedPlainText.length);
            System.out.println("Zero padding to " + (keyLength / 8));
            paddedPlainText = tmp;
        }

        System.out.println("OAEP padded plain text: " + DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(paddedPlainText));

        OAEPParameterSpec paramSpec = new OAEPParameterSpec("SHA-256", "MGF1", MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA1, PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT);
        RSAPadding padding = RSAPadding.getInstance(RSAPadding.PAD_OAEP_MGF1, keyLength / 8, new SecureRandom(), paramSpec);
        byte[] plainText2 = padding.unpad(paddedPlainText);

        System.out.println("Unpadded plain text: " + DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(plainText2));
        return plainText2;
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new Exception("Failed to decrypt AES secret key using RSA.", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Manish Sahni as per code on [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23853610/6326607) i emplimented but receive lHaash mismatch please verify my code what is the problem.